Regression Suite Automation Tool Test plan not available in AzureDevops settings
I created a project in AzureDevops and created a test plan under it. I'm trying to use Regression Suite Automation Tool to execute these tests. When I connected to azureDevops using RSAT using access token I get connection successful popup but my Test plans under the projects are not coming up
Settings Screenshot
Test plans for another project was available for me.
